# Mui V5 - Remove TreeView collapse/extand icons and TreeItem indentation

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, treeview

I'm using Mui V5 and want to change TreeView so it doesnt include collapse/extand icons since I need them to be a part of the TreeItem label component and appear on the left, not right. Also, I want to cancel the indentation of the TreeItems. how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you are trying to do with indentation cannot be directly done through TreeView or TreeItem props. You can remove icons just avoiding `defaultCollapseIcon` and `defaultExpandIcon` props.

You can always add some custom styling to achieve what you want. Here's an example to just get a TreeView without icons nor indentation.

```
const StyledTreeView = styled(TreeView)`
  .MuiTreeItem-group {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
`;

const StyledTreeItem = styled(TreeItem)`
  .MuiTreeItem-iconContainer {
    display: none;
  }
`;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <StyledTreeView aria-label="tree">
      <StyledTreeItem nodeId="1" label="Item 1">
        <StyledTreeItem nodeId="2" label="Subitem 1-1" />
      </StyledTreeItem>
      <StyledTreeItem nodeId="5" label="Item 2">
        <StyledTreeItem nodeId="10" label="Subitem 2-1" />
        <StyledTreeItem nodeId="6" label="Subitem 2-2">
          <StyledTreeItem nodeId="8" label="Subitem 2-2-1" />
        </StyledTreeItem>
      </StyledTreeItem>
    </StyledTreeView>
  );
}
```

The custom style applied to TreeView removes the indentation, and the one applied to StyledTreeItem removes the space assigned to an icon.

[Here's a sandbox with an unintended TreeView](https://codesandbox.io/dashboard/all/?workspace=96455f91-c114-4a2c-84f9-b946346b5247)